# Cannot use variable of type *T as type in argument

Tags: go, generics

I'm learning Go 1.18 generics and I'm trying to understand why I'm having trouble here.  Long story short, I'm trying to `Unmarshal` a protobuf and I want the parameter type in `blah` to "just work".  I've simplified the problem as best I could, and this particular code is reproducing the same error message I'm seeing:

```
./prog.go:31:5: cannot use t (variable of type *T) as type stringer in argument to do:
    *T does not implement stringer (type *T is pointer to type parameter, not type parameter)
```

```
package main

import "fmt"

type stringer interface {
    a() string
}

type foo struct{}

func (f *foo) a() string {
    return "foo"
}

type bar struct{}

func (b *bar) a() string {
    return "bar"
}

type FooBar interface {
    foo | bar
}

func do(s stringer) {
    fmt.Println(s.a())
}

func blah[T FooBar]() {
    t := &T{}
    do(t)
}

func main() {
    blah[foo]()
}
```

I realize that I can completely simplify this example by not using generics (i.e., pass the instance to `blah(s stringer) {do(s)}`.  However, I do want to understand why the error is happening.

What do I need to change with this code so that I can create an instance of `T` and pass that pointer to a function expecting a particular method signature?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your code there's no relationship between the constraints `FooBar` and `stringer`. Furthermore the methods are implemented on the pointer receivers.

A quick and dirty fix for your contrived program is simply to *assert* that `*T` is indeed a `stringer`:

```
func blah[T FooBar]() {
    t := new(T)
    do(any(t).(stringer))
}
```

Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/zmVX56T9LZx

But this forgoes type safety, and could panic at run time. To preserve compile time type safety, another solution that somewhat preserves your programs' semantics would be this:

```
type FooBar[T foo | bar] interface {
    *T
    stringer
}

func blah[T foo | bar, U FooBar[T]]() {
    var t T
    do(U(&t))
}
```

So what's going on here?

First, the relationship between a type parameter and its constraint is not identity: `T` **is not** `FooBar`. You cannot use `T` like it was `FooBar`, therefore `*T` is definitely not equivalent to `*foo` or `*bar`.

So when you call `do(t)`, you're attempting to pass a **type `*T`** into something that expects a `stringer`, but `T`, pointer or not, just does not inherently have the `a() string` method in its type set.

Step 1: add the method `a() string` into the `FooBar` interface (by embedding `stringer`):

```
type FooBar interface {
    foo | bar
    stringer
}
```

But that's not enough yet, because now none of your types actually implement it. Both declare the method on the pointer receiver.

Step 2: change the types in the union to be pointers:

```
type FooBar interface {
    *foo | *bar
    stringer
}
```

This constraint now works, but you have another problem. You can't declare composite literals when the constraint doesn't have a core type. So `t := T{}` is also invalid. We change it to:

```
func blah[T FooBar]() {
    var t T // already pointer type
    do(t)
}
```

Now this compiles, but `t` is actually the zero value of a pointer type, so it's `nil`. Your program doesn't crash because the methods just return some string literal.

If you need to also initialize the memory referenced by the pointers, inside `blah` you need to know about the base types.

Step 3: So you add `T foo | bar` as one type param, and change the signature to:

```
func blah[T foo | bar, U FooBar]() {
    var t T
    do(U(&t))
}
```

Done? Not yet. The conversion `U(&t)` is still invalid because the type set of both `U` and `T` don't match. You need to now parametrize `FooBar` in `T`.

Step 4: basically you extract `FooBar`'s union into a type param, so that at compile time its type set will include only one of the two types:

```
type FooBar[T foo | bar] interface {
    *T
    stringer
}
```

The constraint now can be instantiated with `T foo | bar`, preserve type safety, pointer semantics and initialize `T` to non-nil.

```
func (f *foo) a() string {
    fmt.Println("foo nil:", f == nil)
    return "foo"
}

func main() {
    blah[foo]()
}
```

Prints:

```
foo nil: false
foo
```

Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/src2sDSwe5H

---

If you can instantiate `blah` with pointer types, or even better pass arguments to it, you can remove all the intermediate trickery:

```
type FooBar interface {
    *foo | *bar
    stringer
}

func blah[T FooBar](t T) {
    do(t)
}

func main() {
    blah(&foo{})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer above there are two more ways to solve this problem. In both cases the FooBar type has to be:

```golang
type FooBar interface {
    *foo | *bar
    stringer
}
```

---

### The first one:

Create this generic New func. It does the same as built-in new func, but can be easily passed as a function argument.

```golang
func New[T any]() *T {
    return new(T)
}
```

Modify the blah func to accept and use the _new func.
This function is responsible for creating a FooBar instance.

```golang
func blah[T FooBar](_new func() T) {
    t := _new()
    do(t)
}
```

Modify the main func:

```golang
func main() {
    blah(New[foo])
}
```

Basically we're injecting the built-in new function into a generic function.

[Full solution on a go playground](https://go.dev/play/p/OHauSe7x3yx)

### The second one:

We can use reflection to instantiate a variable of a pointer type hidden behind an interface:

```golang
func gnew[T any]() T {
    var t T
    var _T = reflect.TypeOf(t)
    if _T.Kind() == reflect.Pointer {
        return reflect.New(_T.Elem()).Interface().(T)
    }
    return t
}
```

The blah and the main func will be:

```golang
func blah[T FooBar]() {
    var t = gnew[T]()
    do(t)
}

func main() {
    blah[*foo]()
}
```

[Full solution on a go playground](https://go.dev/play/p/UJ-TWabPZW2)