# Initialize value for pointer in Go Generics

Tags: go, generics

I have a generic func `func foo[T bar]()` which I need to pass a type which is a pointer to a struct `foo[*zab]()`. In func `foo` I want to initialize the value using one of `new()` or `var t T`.

My question is if that is possible and if, how! See the code below (with link to Go playground):

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    foo[*zab]()
}

type bar interface {
    String() string
    SetString(string)
}

func foo[T bar]() {
    var t T
    t.SetString("asdf")
    fmt.Println(t.String()) // Should return "asdf"
}

type zab struct {
    f string
}

func (z zab) String() string {
    return z.f
}

func (z *zab) SetString(f string) {
    z.f = f
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/rLCuvYNem1t

Comment: you have to capture the base type in order to have a non-nil pointer on which to call methods. The linked Q&A shows what it looks like. https://go.dev/play/p/FWn2vYyh4JN

Comment: [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71791637/cannot-use-variable-of-type-t-as-type-in-argument/71793077#71793077) instead is a more step-by-step explanation of how to approach this kind of problems